# extract text from html string with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, string, text, extract

```
html_string "<span class=\"verse\"><strong>1<\/strong>\u00a0hello world how are you?,<span class=\"trans\" title=\"\u00a0Greek brothers.\">t<\/span> I am fine thank you.<\/span><span class=\"verse\"><strong>2<\/strong>\u00a0this world is very bad.<\/span><span class=\"verse\"><strong>3<\/strong>\u00aall me are good,<\/span>"
```

I just want to extract the text inside the span which has class **verse** and it should not include text from span with class **trans**.

The result must be in array form.

from above string I must get result like this

```
["\u00a0hello world how are you? I am fine thank you","\u00a0this world is very bad.","\u00aall me are good,"]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var html_string = "<span class=\"verse\">"
                    + "<strong>1</strong>\u00a0hello world how are you?,"
                    + "<span class=\"trans\" title=\"\u00a0Greek brothers.\">t<\/span> "
                    + "I am fine thank you."
                + "</span>"
                + "<span class=\"verse\">"
                    + "<strong>2</strong>\u00a0this world is very bad."
                + "</span>"
                + "<span class=\"verse\">"
                    + "<strong>3<\/strong>\u00aall me are good,"
                + "</span>";

// Build up the DOM in a hidden element we can parse through
var $html = $('<div>',{html:html_string}).hide().appendTo('body');

// loop through each verse    
$html.find('.verse').each(function(i,e){
    // grab the verse, but first delete any span.trans
    var verse = $(e).find('span.trans').remove().end().text();
    // console.log(verse);
});
// remove the html from the DOM
$html.remove();
```

You should be able to loop it without adding it to the DOM, but for some reason I can't get it to work. Might be because it's late or my fingers are on strike for the evening. Either way, if someone finds a way to do it without attaching it, please post and I'll up-vote.